# Major problems with setrlimit after upgrading to Saucy

Tags: kernel, apache2, 13.10, ulimit

I have been using [setrlimit](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man2/prlimit.2.html) with the R programming language for several versions of Ubuntu. However after upgrading to 13.10, very strange things started happening.

First I started noticing that Apache2 was hitting `RLIMIT_NPROC` which was set to 50, even though Apache actually only seemed to have a couple of processes. See more detail in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19435040/apache-2-4-hits-rlimit-nproc-hidden-processes). I assumed it was a problem related to the upgrade of Apache 2.2 to Apache 2.4.

However now I am also experiencing strange things with `RLIMIT_AS`. In my application I set `RLIMIT_AS` to 1e9 (1GB) for each process, which should be more than enough. However I am randomly getting out of memory errors.

Has something changed between kernel 3.8 and 3.11 in the way `setrlimit` works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There where changes to apparmor that could affect rlimit enforcement in the Ubuntu 3.11 kernel in saucy. Note these changes currently only apply to the Ubuntu Saucy kernel and not to the upstream kernels as saucy is using apparmor patches that have not entered the upstream kernel yet.

If rlimits are not working correctly please file a bug.